# view specific component in another component according to specific condition in angular

Tags: angular, components

I have 5 components , I want to view one of them in another component according to specific condition
for example when x=1 First Component is viewed ,x=2 Second Component is viewed and so on meaning of x is changeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where x is what you would like to test (from your example, x = 1)

```
<div [ngSwitch]="x">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="1">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="2">...</some-other-element>
  <some-other-element-2 *ngSwitchCase="3">...</some-other-element-2>
  <some-other-element-3 *ngSwitchDefault>No matches found</some-element-3>
</div>
```

Reference: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NgSwitch Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) for this

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <!-- the same view can be shown in more than one case -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <!--default case when there are no matches -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

Alternatively, you can also use [NgIf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf), but the NgSwitch is more suitable for single expression for multiple choices.

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```

Comment: I changed the element names in my answer after copying and pasting this...weird how they are using the same element 3 times in the example and change out one - kind of confusing. Docs probably need revised.